# two select box in angular, appearing only one

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create two select box in angular, but only first one is appering, any help!!
HTML :

```
<div><p><span id="countryLocale">
CountryName<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="x for x in names">
</span>
</p>
<p><span id="languageLocale">
Language<select ng-model="selectedLang" ng-options="x for x in langLocale">
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Controller: 
I have define two static array in controller 
                $scope.names = ["INDIA", "France"];
                $scope.langLocale = ["English", "French"];

Answer (score 3):

Close the select tag.

```
<div><p><span id="countryLocale">
CountryName <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="x for x in names" ></select>
</span>
</p>
<p><span id="languageLocale">
Language<select ng-model="selectedLang" ng-options="x for x in langLocale" ></select>
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

**Additional notes**
While I was looking to answer this question, I tried the **below code which didn't work**.

```
<select ng-model="selectedLang" ng-options="x for x in langLocale" />
<select ng-model="selectedLang" ng-options="x for x in langLocale" />
```

This is because in html 5 
`<foo />` is equal to `<foo>` but not `<foo></foo>`

So, select must be used like `<select></select>` but not `<select />`

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the closing tags of the `select` element. Please make use of an editor like that of *Visual Studio*, etc., that highlights the code errors during development.

Please find the working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/db0x378m/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <div>
        <p>
            <span id="countryLocale">
                CountryName<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span id="languageLocale">
                Language<select ng-model="selectedLang" ng-options="x for x in langLocale"></select>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["INDIA", "France"];
    $scope.langLocale = ["English", "French"];
});
```